# Algebra - Sums and Means of two sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had a year of calculus in high school, but proceeded to not use it for six years afterwards. I've returned to school to study higher math but there are some expressions I must have seen before and accepted as given that I don't know how to justify now.

$$\text{Let }\ \{x_1 ... x_n\}\ \text{ and }\ \{y_1...y_n\}\ \text{be real numbers.}$$

I think it that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n * \bar{x}$ and by extension $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, is true. Simple numeric testing has shown it to be true with integers from 1 to 50.

However, I can't justify this equality when I think the algebra is correct.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bar{y} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \times (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)\\
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i
$$

What is the algebraic rule I am missing? I am guessing this is some kind of mistake in assuming "everything" is linear and misusing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using that
$$
\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\Big)\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\Big) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i.
$$
which is certainly not true. For $n=2$ that would imply that
$$
(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2
$$
which obviously doesn't hold. Take for instance $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$.